# How do I get the coordinates (i.e. frame rect) of the caret in a UITextField?

Tags: ios, geometry, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller, caret

I have a `UITextField` where I am implementing autocomplete in a `UIPopoverController`.  I would like the popover's arrow to point directly at the caret (the way Mail and Messages does in the To: field).  How do I get a `CGRect` that represents the location of the caret?

Note: I am not interested in the position in the text string, which is what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427551/how-to-figure-out-the-current-caret-position-in-a-uitextfield) question deals with.  I need a way to get the pixel location of the caret relative to the frame of the `UITextField`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try implementing the below code, it works fine for most of the characters.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = textField.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textField positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textField positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    CGRect caretFrame = [textField caretRectForPosition:end];

    return YES;
}
```